# Stop td making other tds above and below same width

Tags: css, html-table

How can I stop a td with lots of text making the td above it the same length?

In this example the outline for the cell containing '1' shows its as wide as the cell containing 'long text here'. What I want is for the cell containing '1' to only be as wide as it needs to be to fit the text it contains.

Can this be done with CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/r7yXD/1/

```
<table>
 <tr> 
  <td>1</tRund>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>long text here</td>
  <td>.</td>
 </tr>
</table>


td {
border: 1px solid red;
}​
```

So looking at the image below, the first example is what happens and I understand why, but can I make the 2nd option happen instead with CSS?

​[image]

Comment: Then what do you want the "long text here" cell to do? Columns of td's will always be the same size, or else it wont look like a table

Comment: Ive updated by question with an image of what im trying to achieve. I know it wont look like a table but can it be done? Thanks

Comment: That is the default of a table that cells in a column have the same width (to make it a column). If you want dynamic behavior depending on the content, then a table is the wrong element.

Comment: I know its horribly un-semantic but i dont have control over the mark up and tables have been used for layout. This is a short term measure to make the site less bad.

Comment: Your second picture is no longer a table as it is. You can use many separate tables with one row each to achieve this result...

Comment: I cant change the html at all. Is there a CSS way? Even if its a hack...

Comment: If you really can't change the markup itself, the only way I see (perhaps others see better ways) is to manipulate the dom per javascript and change the table and inner elements to other elements like divs and paragraphs. But that is a pile of work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Its the nature of a table to make the td's the same width.

You could however add additional td's and use `colspan="2"`, but to be honest, if you need to do such a thing, especially for texts,  you probably shouln't be using tables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
border: 1px solid red;
}​
</style>

<table>
 <tr> 
  <td>1</td>
  <td colspan="2">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td colspan="2">long text here</td>
  <td>.</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r7yXD/3/ Ive added your code below mine, doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments this is not possible using a `<table>`-element. You can read more about it here at w3.org: "[17.5 Visual layout of table contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layout)".

It says:

> The visual layout of these boxes is governed by a rectangular, irregular grid of rows and columns. Each box occupies a whole number of grid cells, determined according to the following rules.

And interesting for your case is from rule number 5:

> […] Each cell is thus a rectangular box, one or more grid cells wide and high. […]